# How can I store a string(from a file with n number of lines) in a dynamic array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, access-violation

Newb here... taking a C++ class on data structures. I am making a program that takes a list of chores from a text file and stores them in a dynamic array.

```
//In header/ In class:

private:
/* var to keep len of list */
int len = 99; // Not sure what to set this to or if I need to even set it.
/* add appropriate data structure to store list */
string *arr = new string[len];

//In .cpp:

ListOfChores::ListOfChores(string fileName) {
ifstream file(fileName, ifstream::in);
string line;
    if (file.is_open()) //Checking if the file can be opened
    {
        while (!file.eof()) // To get all the lines.
        {
            getline(file, line); // Gets a single line
            arr[len] = line; // Store a line in the array
            len++; // Increases the array size by one
        }
        file.close(); // Closes file
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl; // Gives error if the file can't be opened
}
```

But I am getting an error for storing a line in the array. It says "Access violation reading location." There is another function executed in the main.cpp for printing the lines.

Comment: Off topic: `while (!file.eof()) // To get all the lines.` The comment lies. This will get all of the lines in the file plus one line that is not in the file. More on this bug here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overrun your array buffer at once because `len` is already 99. You should have a notion of `capacity` and `length`. Capacity is the maximum you can store without reallocating, and `length` is the actual number of data lines.

Please avoid this C-style array in C++ code. Use `vector`, which has been around for at least 20 years (STL) if I'm not mistaken.

(you're not a lost cause, you are already using `std::string` :))

Check this:

```
#include <vector>
//In header/ In class:

private:

/* add appropriate data structure to store list */
std::vector<string> arr;   // define a vector

//In .cpp:

ListOfChores::ListOfChores(string fileName) {
ifstream file(fileName, ifstream::in);
string line;
    if (file.is_open()) //Checking if the file can be opened
    {
       while (getline(file, line))
       {
           arr.push_back(line);
       }
        file.close(); // Closes file
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl; // Gives error if the file can't be opened
}
```

Now `arr.size()` holds the number of lines, it is no longer limited to 99 lines but to the max. program memory capacity. You can still access line number 13 by `arr[12]` or `arr.at(12)` for boundary checked access.

proper way to iterate through it (C++11) for instance to print all lines:

```
for (auto s : arr)
{
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Now, if you REALLY have to use an array, you can emulate/mimic what `vector` does (well, not as performant I'm sure, but does the job):

```
private:

 int len=0;
 int capacity=100;
 string *arr = new string[capacity];
```

now in the code, just before inserting (untested, but the idea is right):

```
if (len>=capacity)
{
   string *narr = new string[capacity+100];
   for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
   {
        narr[i] = arr[i];
   }
   delete [] arr;
   arr = narr;
   capacity += 100; // growth
}
```

(you cannot use `realloc` or `memcpy` because you're handling objects in the arrays)

Comment: I would love to use this but the assignment requires us to use an array T_T

Comment: BTW it was worse than I thought. Check my edit (first lines).

Comment: Thanks so much. Yeah, I'm quite new to this -- my education in programming is minimal. Care to explain how I might emulate what vector does?

Comment: Could we get a correction on the `while (!file.eof())` that was copied from the question source? No point leaving a bug like that in the answer.

Comment: `while (getline(file, line)) {arr.push_back(line);}` will do everything that is needed thanks to [the magic of `operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: even better! edited (again). I'm a bit rusty when it comes to C++ file I/O. thx.

Comment: Now what would I do if we were required to use `unique_ptr`?

Comment: I think you can gather your now working source and ask a new (good) question about it. I'm not telling that to annoy you. I'm not able to answer on `unique_ptr`, but others will certainly. That's a completely different question.